# Any reference for a good free tamil font for android app

Tags: android, fonts, tamil

I have an android application that displays content in tamil. I understand how I can display tamil fonts in my application by adding a font.

My problem is, the fonts that are being used for web is not properly displaying in android app. So, the questions are..

- My content is stored in db in UTF-8 format. So, If I display this in the client side, do you have any ref for free tamil fonts that I can use in my app?
- I saw some references about TSCII fonts. If I want to use that in my app, should I store the content also in TSCII encoding? Or Can I store the content in UTF-8 and display using TSCII font?

Thanks

Comment: Mayu, if you store everything in UTF8, you shouldn't need any special fonts to display the text. Can you provide more details? How are you inputting the data into the DB? What encoding are you using at the DB level?

Answer (score 1):

try Bamini, it works for my application.

http://www.jagatheswara.com/tamil.php

Comment: It doesnt work properly in my application. Does anyone know a good tamil font that can be used in our application for Android 2.3.3?

Comment: If you directly place the font, it won't work. U need to do some workaround to show the font. Did you check the source here https://github.com/mayooresan/Android-Tamil

Comment: Hi Mayu, Is it possible to show english characters with Bamini font? I have 3 english words to be shown in between. Is it possible some how?

Comment: @KarthikPalanivelu If you wanna use English chars also then plz use some other TSCII fonts. Don't use Bamini. It'll convert all English letters into Tamil letters too.

Comment: Actually my requirement is different. I need to have menu both in English and Tamil based on the locale settings. i.e. Application should show menu in tamil only when the language setting is tamil. Likewise for English. SO, I created 8 menu items 4 in tamil and 4 in enlgish. Set bamini font for tamil menu items and normal Serif for English menu items. Using OnPrepareOptionsMenu() I make menu items visible and invisible. It works perfect in 2.3.3. But in 4.1 it's messed up. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have no idea. If you have locale provided in the langugae file it should according to the system settings. BTW Tamil is not supported yet as system language right?? As far as I know you need to do it via 3rd party apps,

Comment: I think from 4.1, It's a system language. Because it works without setting typeface. And so, now i made separate code for menu to support 4.1.2 and separate code to support 2.3.3. It works :)