# Android 2.2 webview not supporting Tamil font

Tags: android, utf-8, android-webview, tamil

i am developing new android application...i tried load html content in webview in 2.2 emulator but not supporting tamil font

here my code...

```
WebView learn2crack = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
learn2crack.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
learn2crack.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
learn2crack.loadUrl("http://www.dinamalar.com/");
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry this is not a solution to your problem and I'm not even sure there is a workaround but a lot of fonts / character sets weren't supported in older versions of Android.

Comment: You could try the link in the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319405/any-reference-for-a-good-free-tamil-font-for-android-app?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your link,but that's not for webview

Comment: finally i solved the issue for android lower version

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bamini.ttf");    
    String tamil_string="செய்திகள்";
    //creating intance of TamilFotnUtil Class
    TamilFontUtil tfUtil = new TamilFontUtil();

   //Convert Tamil font encording using the utility.
    String tamilStringEncoded =  tfUtil.convertTamilString(tamil_string);
```

add below line inside the the style

```
@font-face {font-family: MyCustomFont; src: url("Bamini.ttf")}body {font-family: MyCustomFont, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: medium; color: black}"
```

for example

```
<html> <head>

 <title>example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

 <style type="text/css">@font-face {font-family: MyCustomFont; src: 

url(file:///android_asset/Bamini.ttf)}body {font-family: MyCustomFont, Verdana, Arial, 

sans-serif; font-size: medium; color: black}</head><body>

<h1>tamilStringEncoded </h1></body></html>
```

finally load data into webview ....