# how to make gujrati font supported in android app

Tags: android, utf-8

i'm going make a web site in which i have lots of Gujarati language text.
i found that in many cell phones (Micromax canvas2,etc) Gujarati language is not supported.
so i'm thinking to make a web browser in android which support Gujarati font. so user can use that my web site through my android browser.
plzz help me quickly

Answer (score 0):

Few devices doesn't support Gujarati language packs.
You need to define css and apply it to your webview.

Below post may help you as well.
[Android 2.2 webview not supporting Tamil font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422043/android-2-2-webview-not-supporting-tamil-font?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this this will work fine

```
TextView mtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_settings); 

           Typeface face1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), 

                     "Lohit-Gujarati.ttf"); 

           mtxt.setTypeface(face1); 

           mtxt.setText("પૂર્વ વડાપ્રધાન રાજીવ ગાંધીની હત્યા કરનારા 3 આરોપીઓની ફાંસીની સજા સુપ્રિમ કોર્ટે ઉમ્રકેદમાં ફેરવી નાંખી છે.આમ રાજીવગાંધીના" + 

                     "3 હત્યારાઓને હવે ફાંસીની સજા નહી થાય.સુપ્રીમ કોર્ટમાં 3 જજોની બેન્ચે આજે આ ચુકાદો આ");
```

Comment: i tried this code. but it isn't working.
i am trying to fetch data which is already stored in mysql remote database.so please suggest me example code/tutorial.i required its urgently.

Comment: see this link add comment there http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2014/02/gujarati-language-font-support-android.html